# Automatic document generation based on a database

Tags: automation, python

I want to automatically create business card based on a database containing my employees' data. (i.e. to generate **one `.pdf` file per person, filling in a pre-filled document with the information of the database**).

I have a database (a `.csv` file) that looks like this:

```
Employee ID, Last Name, First name, Telephone number, Additional informations
001, Dylan, Bob, 012345, Some stuff
007, Doe, John, 01452, 
002, Doe, Jane, , A lot of \emph{informations} with \LaTeX commands that are very long \newline and maybe should be displayed on several lines etc. \begin{itemize} \item fus \item ro \item dah! \end{itemize}
```

My `.tex` file that defines the look of the PDF is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{#EmplyeeID.jpg}
    {\sffamily #FirstName \textsc{#LastName}}
    \newline
    \section{Phone}
    {\tiny #telephone number}
    \newpage
    #AdditionalInformations
\end{document}
```

I want the LaTeX file to read the second row of the database, replace the `#Fields` by their values, generate a PDF and then start again with a new line - as long as necessary.

I looked at the `datatool` package, I am able to load the database (`\DTLloaddb[autokeys]{DB}{my_db.csv}`). But I'm going blank regarding two points:

1. How to read only the n-th element of the m-th row?
2. How to generate a PDF and repeat with `m:=m+1`?

Thanks for any help (fixing these issues or indicating packages I should look at)!

Comment: There are LaTeX methods to do this.  Alternatively, it is very easy to write a script in a language such as Python that is made for combining tools.   Reading the .csv file is easy with such a language, as is writing a .tex file and then invoking a system command such as 'pdflatex fn'.  (The ease with which you can write such scripts is a strength of TeX-based solutions.)

Comment: So I should write a Python-script that generates n `.tex` files that I automatically compile via a terminal command (I always use TeXmaker, but I'm not afraid of fiddling some code !), right ?
That's the kind of new solution ways I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: (not directed at the main point of the question,)  if the "additional information" (or any other field) contains commas, they should best be "hidden" by enclosing them in braces, to avoid confusion in the parsing.

Comment: Do you absolutely want one PDF file output per business card, or is it acceptable to have them on different pages, but all in one file? You should clarify in any case (*n* files, one file or both allowed).

Comment: In the real case this example refers to, I want a PDF-file per business card. But see my answer edited with your suggestion - thx.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following [Jim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270714/automatic-document-generation-based-on-a-database/270928#comment650017_270714)'s suggestion, I wrote down an Python-code that does what I wanted to do.

Even if it is more Python oriented, I think it might be interesting to post the answer here.
(Since we're TeXer here, and maybe not Python-ers, there are 'for dummies' explanations - sorry for length.)

---

## Needed files

You need following files in your working directory :

- A python-file named `routine.py` containing the code herein below,
- A csv-database named `database.csv`, with following structure:

  ```
  Employee ID, Last Name, Fist name, Telephone number, Additional informations
  001, Dylan, Bob, 012345, Some stuff
  007, Doe, John, 01452,
  002, Doe, Jane, , "A lot of \emph{informations} with \LaTeX commands, and commas as well. \newline It can be displayed on several lines. \begin{itemize} \item fus \item ro \item dah! \end{itemize}"
  ```

(Note that there is a header - the python routine will then skip the first line)

- One picture per employee. This picture should be named according to following pattern : `EmployeeID.extention` (E.g. in this example, you need three pictures : `001.jpg`, `002.png`, `007.jpg` - note that the format might not be the same over the pictures)

---

## The Python code

Considering [Dirk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270714/automatic-document-generation-based-on-a-database?noredirect=1#comment650628_270714)'s suggestion, you have two options : either you generate one PDF-file per business card, or you generate one PDF-file with all the business card. You'll find both versions of the Python-routine herein below.

Please look at embedded comments for explanations.

- ### To create one PDF-file per business card

The global operating is following :

1. the routine reads a row of the `.csv` database,
2. generates a customized LaTeX code,
3. and compiles this.
4. Then, it repeats the process (steps 1 to 3) for each row.

```py
###== imported packages ==###
import csv
import subprocess # cf "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683123/
                  # compile-latex-from-python" for original example

###== Definition of the LaTeX template (with "blanks") ==###
    # caution : you need to escape backslashs with backslashs
    #   blanks are filed with %(Name)s 
    # Name are here two letters
    # 's' means the variable is a string
LatexContent = '''\\documentclass{scrartcl}
                        \\usepackage{graphicx}
                        \\begin{document}
                            \\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{%(Id)s}
                            {\\sffamily %(Fn)s \\textsc{%(Ln)s}}
                                \\newline
                            \\section{Phone}
                            {\\tiny Phone number: %(Ph)s}
                                \\newpage
                            %(Ot)s
                   \\end{document}'''

###== Look at the database ==##
# open the database into python
my_db_file = open("database.csv","rb")

# read the database
my_db = csv.reader(my_db_file, delimiter=',',skipinitialspace=True)

###== TeX files processing and generating ==###
#skip the header of the database
my_db.next() 

#then for each row of the database
for row in my_db :
        ## Assign the items of the row to the variables that will fill up the 
        ##    blanks of the LaTeX code
        ID = str(row[0])            #caution, first item of a row = index '0'
        LastName = str(row[1])
        FirstName = str(row[2])
        Phone = str(row[3])
        Other = str(row[4])

            #define the TeX file name
        TexFileName = ID + '.tex'

        ## create a new LaTeX file with the blanks filled
            #create a new file
        TexFile = open(TexFileName,'w')

            #fill the blanks with the previously read informations
        TexFile.write(LatexContent %{"Id" : ID, "Fn" : FirstName, 
        "Ln" : LastName, "Ph" : Phone, "Ot" : Other })

            #close the file
        TexFile.close()

        ## compile the file you've just created with LaTeX        
        subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',TexFileName],shell=False)      

        ##repeate for each row

#close the database file
my_db_file.close()
```

- ### To create only one PDF with all the business cards

  The global operating is here slightly different :

  1. the routine generates the head of the `.tex` file,
  2. reads a row of the `.csv` database,
  3. generates a customized TeX code, and append it to the existing `.tex` file,
  4. repeats steps 2 and 3 for each row
  5. appends the bottom of the TeX code to the existing `.tex` file,
  6. finally compiles the `.tex` file.

```py
###== imported packages ==###
import csv
import subprocess # cf "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683123/
                  # compile-latex-from-python" for original example

###== Definition of the LaTeX template (with "blanks") ==###
    # caution : you need to escape backslashs with backslashs
    #   blanks are filed with %(Name)s 
    # Name are here two letters
    # 's' means the variable is a string

LaTeXpreamble='''\\documentclass{scrartcl}
                        \\usepackage{graphicx}
                        \\begin{document}'''

LaTeXcodePerBusinessCard='''\\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm]{%(Id)s}
                            {\\sffamily %(Fn)s \\textsc{%(Ln)s}}
                                \\newline
                            \\section{Phone}
                            {\\tiny Phone number: %(Ph)s}
                                \\newpage
                            %(Ot)s
                            \\null'''
LaTeXinBetween='''\\newpage'''

LaTeXcolophon='''\\end{document}'''

###== Look at the database ==##
# open the database into python
my_db_file = open("database.csv","rb")

# read the database
my_db = csv.reader(my_db_file, delimiter=',',skipinitialspace=True)

###== TeX files processing and generating ==###
#skip the header of the database
my_db.next()

#create a new textfile
    #define its name
TexFileName = 'businessCards.tex' 

    #create the file
TexFile = open(TexFileName,'w')

    #copy the preamble
TexFile.write(LaTeXpreamble)

    #close the file and re-open it in 'append' mode
TexFile.close()
TexFile = open(TexFileName,'a')

#then for each row of the database
for row in my_db :
        ## Assign the items of the row to the variables that will fill up the 
        ##    blanks of the LaTeX code
        ID = str(row[0])            #caution, first item of a row = index '0'
        LastName = str(row[1])
        FirstName = str(row[2])
        Phone = str(row[3])
        Other = str(row[4])


        ## add a piece of code with the blanks filled

            #fill the blanks with the previously read informations
        LaTeXcodeToAdd = LaTeXcodePerBusinessCard %{"Id" : ID, 
        "Fn" : FirstName, "Ln" : LastName, "Ph" : Phone, "Ot" : Other }

            #append this code to the .tex file
        TexFile.write(LaTeXcodeToAdd)

            #append the 'in-between' code to separate two business cards
        TexFile.write(LaTeXinBetween)

        ##repeate for each row

#append the colophon to finish the .tex filed
TexFile.write(LaTeXcolophon)

#close the file
TexFile.close()

## compile the .tex file with pdfLaTeX        
subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',TexFileName],shell=False)   

#close the database file
my_db_file.close()
```

---

## How to process?

1. Open your terminal
2. Browse to the directory containing aforementioned files
3. Execute the command `python routine.py`

That's all !